# How to set font features (stylistics sets) in MJML

Tags: html, css, email, templates, mjml

I am trying to get `font-feature-settings` CSS integrated into an MJML template.

I tried integrating it in mj-all attributes like

```
<mj-all font-family="Space Grotesk, Arial" font-size="22px" color="#212B39" font-feature-settings="ss04" />
```

as well as putting it on different css classes within `mj-style` like

```
<mj-style>
    html {
        font-feature-settings: "pnum" on,"lnum" on,"ss04" on;
    }
</mj-style>
```

None of that seems to work. From what I could see there's no official support in MJML for that and setting it globally through CSS doesn't seem to work - at least for the email clients I tried.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<mj-head>
    <mj-attributes>
      <mj-text font-size="48px" color="#483F38" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" />
    </mj-attributes>
  </mj-head>
```

[live example](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/fHF7KFMcw)
[doc](https://documentation.mjml.io/#mj-attributes)